# blkid not working immediately after cdrecord

Tags: mount, data-cd

I have a product based on a CentOS 6.3 system. One of our features is that the user can spit their data out to a CDROM. In making some fixes, I've run into a weird issue - immediately after the cdrecord call, we try to mount the disk, however `mount -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom` fails with 'mount: you must specify the filesystem type'. If you use `mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom`, it works great, OR if you eject and re-insert the disk, it works fine.

A little bit of investigation turns up the fact that immediately after the cdrecord (and until the disk is ejected and re-inserted), `blkid /dev/sr0` doesn't return anything, but works fine after eject/insert.

Is this normal behavior? Is there some state in the CDROM drive that causes this, and is there some way to reset it without the eject cycle? For now I'm returning to (and documenting!) the previous behavior of specifying the file system in this instance.

Versions:

`mount -V`

mount from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 (with libblkid and selinux support)

`blkid -v`

blkid from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 (libblkid 2.17.0, 22-Mar-2010)

`cdrecord -version`

Cdrecord-yelling-line-to-tell-frontends-to-use-it-like-version 2.01.01a03-dvd
Wodim 1.1.9
Copyright (C) 2006 Cdrkit suite contributors
Based on works from Joerg Schilling, Copyright (C) 1995-2006, J. Schilling

Comment: Does mounting with `-t iso9660` work fine directly after burning, or does it just happen to work because it's the second time you tried to mount it? I'd suspect that using `blkid` more than once would also start working. That said, I've seen cd burn software say "reloading disc tray to reset" so it mey be necessary on some drives, which is why I wonder why using `-t iso9660` with `mount` would cause it to start working.

Comment: -t iso9660 works directly after burning. blkid will NOT start working until you eject/reinsert the disc. Note that mounting with -t iso9660 does NOT cause blkid to start working.

Comment: I have heard of drives that need an eject/insert cycle after a burn to work properly. Does `eject -T` work on your drive (to close the tray)? Then you can fully automate it.

Comment: @derobert - unfortunately, it's a drive designed for laptops - insertion is manual, so `eject -T` is not an option for us.

Comment: I would suggest doing `strace -o failed -f blkid /dev/sr0` after a burn, and then `strace -o working -f blkid /dev/sr0` after eject/insert. Then `diff` will hopefully show you what failed, and that'll hopefully help tracking it down.

Comment: You are not using cdrecord but a defective fork created by some unfriendly Debian people. This fork has aprox. 100 documented bugs but the creators of the fork did never try to fix these bugs. I recommend to use maintained original software.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have time to follow @derobert's advice and run strace on the thing at this moment (other tasks await). For the current release, I've simply added `-t iso9660` to the mount command after the `cdrecord` call, which gets around the problem nicely. Given that my software just recorded the cd, I can be quite certain that the filesystem is iso9660 in this case, so I can get away with this trick for the indefinite future.

Answer (score 0):

The programs you used are from a defective fork and Linux distros that do not distribute the original cdrecord but a fork created in May 2004 never uptated the software to get more recent features and bug fixes. Distros that ship "wodim" also ship other defective software like e.g. genisoimage instead of a real mkisofs.

Even the original mkisofs from May 2004 had many bugs but the Debian genisoimage added a lot of additional bugs in 2004.

In Summer 2006 all known bugs have been fixed in the original software and since May 2004 (when the fork you are using has been created) the original software doubled it's features.

The genisoimage you have been using, creates filesystem images with structural bugs. If you have problems, I recommend to upgrade to a recent original software from:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrtools/files/

If auto filesystem detection does not work, this is either caused by problems in the actual filesystem or by a bug in the detection software.

If your problem does not go away when you check with a filesystem image that has been created by the real mkisofs, please make a bug report against the detection software.

Comment: You can use this repository to install it into your Ubuntu installation easily (warning: dpkg dependency checks will constantly emit a mismatch message as genisoimage is hardcoded in ubuntu metapackages):
 

 
https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools/+packages

Comment: Unfortuntely, this has not been updated since a year, even though the "schilytools" consolidation got several new releases since then.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/ubuntu/unstable provides the updated version

Comment: This seems to be old as well, since 3.01a09 is from 2017 and 3.01a10 would b from 2018, so this is several years old. Probably the person did not grok that frequent updates are in schilytools since a while.